# Stored procedure parameter check for not empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Test
    @IGLNO VARCHAR(10) != ''
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE IGLNO = @IGLNO
END
```

Here instead of hardcoding `!=''`, I am trying to use parameter `@IGLNO` with default `NOT NULL` or not empty string.

Can we do something like this in SQL?

Comment: You can set a default parameter value in case something is not passed for the parameter. If you want to use some value if null or empty is passed, you can use a Case statement in your Where clause or you can use an if statement to not execute the query if null or empty param. Depends on what you want to return if null or empty param is passed to procedure

Comment: If the default is not null and not '' then what is it?

Comment: @Dale K, I had exactly the same question!  After I thought about it, I decided it was any valid string... which made me think wildcard match, which brought me to  ` LIKE '_%'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the LIKE operator for a pattern match.

`'_%'` matches a string with at least one character.  It will exclude empty strings as well as nulls.

`'%'` would include empty strings but exclude nulls.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Test
    @IGLNO VARCHAR(10) = '_%'
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE IGLNO LIKE @IGLNO
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **CASE** Stmt:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Test
@IGLNO VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE IGLNO = CASE WHEN @IGLNO='' THEN IGLNO ELSE @IGLNO END
END
```

Comment: `case` *expression* even